# Using a PrintDialog

Tags: java, printing, range, bufferedimage, printdialog

I have a class that implements Printable. in that class I have a public method that creates a List of BufferedImages with each one printed on one page. Now I want to add a PrintDialog, to allow the user to choose the pages to print and the number of copies to print.

I've done some research on the internet and found I probably have to use the `Book` class, but I don't see how to use that in my situation.

Can anyone provide an example? Thanks for your help...

ok. Here's the code I'm using:

```
/**
 * Starts the print job
 * Allows variable scaling
 */
public void startPrint(float scale, JTable rowHeader, JTable mainTable, boolean includeRowHeaders, boolean includeColumnHeaders) throws PrinterException{
    //getPages returns a List<BufferedImage
    this.pages = getPages(scale, rowHeader, mainTable, includeRowHeaders, includeColumnHeaders);
    this.numberOfPages = this.pages.size();

    HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    attr.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0f, 0f, 612/72f, 792/72f, MediaPrintableArea.INCH));
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(this);
    job.print(attr);
}
```

***EDIT***
Ok. I've made some progress. New problem now. I can select page ranges now, but the PrintDialog copies JSpinner is unresponsive and no matter what the JSpinner textfield contains, the print method is always invoked twice for each page. Here's my code...

```
/**
 * Starts the print job
 * Allows variable scaling
 */
public void startPrint(float scale, JTable rowHeader, JTable mainTable, boolean includeRowHeaders, boolean includeColumnHeaders) throws PrinterException{
    //getPages returns a List<BufferedImage>
    this.pages = getPages(scale, rowHeader, mainTable, includeRowHeaders, includeColumnHeaders);
    this.numberOfPages = this.pages.size();

    HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    attr.add(new JobName("Test Print", null));
    attr.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0f, 0f, 612/72f, 792/72f, MediaPrintableArea.INCH));
    attr.add(new PageRanges(1, this.numberOfPages));
    attr.add(new Copies(1));
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(this);

    if(job.printDialog(attr)){
        job.print(attr);
    }
}

/**
 * The actual print routine
 * Prints the class level List<BufferedImage>
 * one after another
 */
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException
{
    if (pageIndex > this.numberOfPages - 1){
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
    else{
        graphics.drawImage(this.pages.get(pageIndex), 0, 0, null);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pageIndex);
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what code you currently have.  Describing the situation is well and good, but it's a _lot_ easier for people to help if they can actually see what you're dealing with, and try it on their own systems.

Comment: While you're making that edit, it would be helpful if you added a tag for the language you're using. And what *Book* class are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken in my edited question. I was testing on Microsoft XPS Document Writer. When I transferred the project to another PC with a real physical printer it works fine...